# Creating layout for a specific browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I have an asp.net-mvc3 website.
I created all the layout using css. The layout is exactly how I want it on firefox and Chrome, but on internet explorer it is in a big mess.

So now i am trying to fix it.

But the problem is that I want to fix it without messing it on firefox or chrome.

Do I have to restart from scratch and rebuild the layout? or is there a way to specify a certain layout for a specific browser.

Something like this:

If Internet Explorer then use this css sheet or style, else use what I allready have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use these(put it on the head):

Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 5 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 5.5 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 5.5000]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie55.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 5.5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is so rubbish :)  Use http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ instead - then you only need one CSS file.

Comment: the first one is for all IEs -_-

Comment: Paul's way is much better in practice. You could always add one on for all IE. In practice you'll only ever need one for ie6,7 and 8 - the others are fine. As an aside, IE10 doesn't respond to ccs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional IE stylesheets.

Create your stylesheets that you want only IE to use, and put them in the document head inside IE specific code.  For example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This will call the all-ie-only.css stylesheet on any version of IE, but you can change the code to be specific versions, or even a group of versions, e.g. "less than IE9"

This is a great resource that has all the info - http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ ([Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383277/310174) has copied and pasted exact content in this answer for you)

Answer (score 1):

You have to identify the problem(s) (which likely have something to do with using Quirks mode) and address them.

There isn't a magic bullet that solves all IE woes, and providing a completely different stylesheet is usually much more work then you need to do.

You can provide code specifically for IE using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), but in the vast majority of cases this should be applied with a light touch.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to be able to get very consistent design across IE, Safari, Opera and Firefox by using a complete reset.css stylesheet.

The reset.css will "0 out" the differing preset standards for each browser and then load your actual stylesheet on a clean slate.

Only after testing the reset.css and stylesheet-name.css do I create browser specific hacks. This is the best practice for consistent display across multiple browsers.

The following link is a good example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is an `<!--[if IE]>` tag. This [website](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) goes through it in detail.

However, in the future you can build a site to work cross platform without the need for If IE tags. It all depends on your CSS and markup.